# What is the formal definition of a combinational logic?

Tags: logic, computer-science, automata, regular-expressions

## Question Background

A finite-state machine can be defined as a 5-tuple as follows (Sipser, pg. 35):

[image: Definition of Finite Automaton]

The image below (taken from [the Wikipedia article on autamata theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory)) seems to suggest that combinational logics can be used to define formal grammars that describe formal languages just the same as regular expressions/FSMs, pushdown automatons, and turing machines.

[image: Automata Theory]

## The Question

Is this, in fact, the case? And if so, **what is the formal definition of a combinational logic**? Is it a finite automata/5-tuple that has a transition function that always specifies a transition to it's one and only state (since it is time-indepedent)? **NOTE**: I consider it inappropriate to couple boolean logic and digital circuitry to a mathematical model which should strive for maximal generalization.

## References

Sipser, *Introduction to the Theory of Computation*, (2nd Edition). Thompson Course Technology, 2006.

Comment: That exact image also appear on the Wikipedia page on combinational logic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinational_logic

Comment: The image does appear on that page which also, unfortunately, lacks a formal definition of combinational logic in the flavor of the ones given for FSA/PSA/Turing automata.

Comment: Seems pretty clear from that wikipedia page that Combinational Logic refers to Boolean Algebra.

Comment: I did the same but didn't see what I would consider a formal definition of a combinational logic with the same kind of rigor notational flavor that is given for FSA/PSA/Turing machines although one is gestured at when it is written that "This is in contrast to sequential logic, in which the output depends not only on the present input but also on the history of the input. In other words, sequential logic has memory while combinational logic does not." I consider it inappropriate to couple boolean logic and digital circuitry to a mathematical model which should strive for maximal generalization